# How do I modify object key value in an array of objects and return the initial array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following array of objects. Each object is a legend element in a doughnut chart. What I want to achieve is that when I click on one element, the `innerRadius` should be set to value 2. If I click on another element, the `innerRadius` value of the previous one should be set to 0. So in the end only the element that I clicked on should have the value 2.

```
export const table1 = [
  {
    label: "p",
    angle: 5,
    style: {fill: "#1A3177"},
    innerRadius: 0,
    active: false,
    key: 0
  },{
    label: "ne",
    angle: 2,
    style: {fill: "#79C7E3"},
    innerRadius: 0,
    active: false,
    key: 1
  },{
    label: "nu",
    angle: 2,
    style: {fill: "#12939A"},
    innerRadius: 0,
    active: false,
    key: 2
  },{
    label: "na",
    angle: 1,
    style: {fill: "#FF9833"},
    innerRadius: 0,
    active: false,
    key: 3
  }
]
```

I have tried to `map` the initial array, apply a `filter`, `reduce`, `splice`.
What I have tried so far it returns the array of objects with the `innerRadius` value of 2 for all the elements that I clicked on

```
 toogleHighlightOn = key => {
    let item = table1.map(i => i)
    let aaa = item.filter(i => i.key === key).reduce(i => i)
    aaa.innerRadius = 2
    const index = item.indexOf(aaa)
    item.splice([index], 1, aaa)

    console.log(aaa)
    console.log(table1)
    return this.setState({
      default: [...item]
    })
  }
```

Comment: `let item = table1.map(i => i)` what are trying to do with this map the same value back without even any change ?

Comment: `let aaa = item.filter(i => i.key === key).reduce(i => i)`  here what are you trying to do with reduce ?

Comment: Did you write the code above? If so, I think you should take a look at what `map` and `reduce` do, because I don't think you're understanding their behavior. If you think you're aware of that, please explain the code you wrote so that we can help you, since giving you a solution is probably not going to help you in any way, right now.

Comment: with the map I want to create a clone of the original array and with filter and reduce to extract the object that is clicked on. after this I am passing the value of the innerRadius to 2 and replace it in the array...

Comment: Instead of `let item = table1.map(i => i)` try `let item = table1.map(obj => { ...obj })`. Objects are copied using reference. So even if you make a copy of array, inner objects are still referred using reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
toggleHighlightOn = key => {
    table1.forEach(i => i.innerRadius = 0);
    const newElement = table1.find(i => i.key === key);
    if (newElement) {
        newElement.innerRadius = 2;
    }

    return this.setState({
      default: [...table1]
    })
}
```